# Iterating over a list of dictionaries in python to find all occurances of a pair of values

Tags: python, dictionary

I searched for some time, but couldn't find an exact solution to my problem. I have a list of dictionaries in format:

```
d = [{"sender": "a", "time": 123, "receiver": "b", "amount": 2}, {"sender": "c", "time": 124, "receiver": "b", "amount": 10}, {"sender": "a", "time": 130, "receiver": "b", "amount": 5}]
```

I would like to find the best way to iterate over all the dictionaries and count how many times a given pair of sender-receiver occurs and the sum of the total amount.

So I would like to get:

```
result = [{"sender": "a", "receiver":b, "count": 2, "total_amount":7}, {"sender": "c", "receiver":b, "count": 1, "total_amount":10}]
```

I am pretty sure I can probably make this work by iterating over all the dictionaries in the list one by one, saving the information in a temporary dictionary, but that will lead to a lot of nested if loops. I was hoping there is a cleaner way to do this.

I know I can use [Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#counter-objects) to count the number of occurences for a unique value:

```
from collections import Counter
Counter(val["sender"] for val in d)
```

which will give me:

```
>>> ({"a":2, "c":1})
```

but how can I do this for a pair of values and have separate dictionaries for each?

Thank you in advance and I hope my question was clear enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one approach using a simple iteration with `dict` methods.

**Ex:**

```
d = [{"sender": "a", "time": 123, "reciever": "b", "amount": 2}, {"sender": "c", "time": 124, "reciever": "b", "amount": 10}, {"sender": "a", "time": 130, "reciever": "b", "amount": 5}]
result = {}
for i in d:
    key = (i['sender'], i['reciever'])
    # del i['time']  # if you do not need `time` key
    if key not in result:
        i.update({'total_amount': i.pop('amount'), 'count': 1})
        result[key] = i
    else:
        result[key]['total_amount'] += i['amount']
        result[key]['count'] += 1

print(list(result.values()))
```

**Output:**

```
[{'count': 2, 'reciever': 'b', 'sender': 'a', 'time': 123, 'total_amount': 7},
 {'count': 1, 'reciever': 'b', 'sender': 'c', 'time': 124, 'total_amount': 10}]
```

Comment: @Jan I did not use it because of multiple key-value modifications

Comment: Plus one for getting his actual expected result down

Comment: as @ege said this is the result I want to get as I want to afterwards be able to write the output to a json file to be displayed using javascript on a website. I will count this as the real answer but ege 's answer is also very useful

Answer (score 2):

Pure python way is to create a new hash table of `sender:reciever` pairs

I **UPDATED** it to count the `total amount` as requested as well.

```
d = [{"sender": "a", "time": 123, "reciever": "b", "amount": 2},
     {"sender": "c", "time": 124, "reciever": "b", "amount": 10},
     {"sender": "a", "time": 130, "reciever": "b", "amount": 5}]

nd = {}

for o in d:
  sender = o['sender']
  recv = o['reciever']
  amount = o['amount']

  k = sender + ":" + recv
  if k not in nd:
    nd[k] = (0, 0)

  nd[k] = (nd[k][0] + 1, nd[k][1] + amount)

print nd
```

which results in `{'c:b': (1, 10), 'a:b': (2, 7)}`

Comment: Thank you for the answer. As I mentioned under the answer of @Rakesh that one is the closest to what I want as i want to write the output to json and be able to display it using javascript on a website so I would like to have dictionary with all the keys present. But your answer is also very helpful if i need to do such types of operations again on dictionaries.

Answer (score 1):

You could use pandas to parse the list of dictionaries into a dataframe.
The dataframe would allow you to easily sum over the `amount` field for certain sender receiver pairs.

```
import pandas as pd

dict = [{"sender": "a", "time": 123, "receiver": "b", "amount": 2},   
        {"sender": "c", "time": 124, "receiver": "b", "amount": 10},   
        {"sender": "a", "time": 130, "receiver": "b", "amount": 5}]

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(dict)
group = df.groupby(by=['sender', 'receiver'])

result = group.sum()
result['occurrences'] = group.size()
print(result)
```

will output

```
                 time  amount  occurrences
sender receiver
a      b          253       7            2
c      b          124      10            1
```

Comment: Good answer, but it doesn't count how many times a sender receiver pair occurs?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38174164/7951589) helps to both at once

Comment: Includes occurrences now, although I would go for the pure python approach at this point.

Answer (score 1):

[Max Crous's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58995661/7951589) answer is more elegant than this, but in case you'd like to avoid extra libraries: this is a pure python way:

```py
import collections
result = collections.defaultdict(lambda : [0,0])
for e in d: 
    result[(e['sender'],e['reciever'])][0]+=e['amount']
    result[(e['sender'],e['reciever'])][1]+=1
```

Result is now a dictionary with tuples of sender and reciever as keys and 2-element lists [total_amount, count] as values

Answer (score 0):

Imo the easiest and cleanest solution would be to use a `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

dct = [{"sender": "a", "time": 123, "reciever": "b", "amount": 2},
       {"sender": "c", "time": 124, "reciever": "b", "amount": 10},
       {"sender": "a", "time": 130, "reciever": "b", "amount": 5}]

result = defaultdict(int)
for item in dct:
    key = "{}:{}".format(item["sender"], item["reciever"])
    result[key] += item["amount"]

print(result)
```

Which results in

```
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'a:b': 7, 'c:b': 10})
```

Besides, don't call your variables `dict` or `list`.

Answer (score 0):

using dictionary you can set sender as key and values as receiver and amount and then increment/add receiver,amount

```
dict = [{"sender": "a", "time": 123, "reciever": "b", "amount": 2}, {"sender": "c", "time": 124, "reciever": "b", "amount": 10}, {"sender": "a", "time": 130, "reciever": "b", "amount": 5}]
dict1={}
for eachitem in dict:
        if(eachitem["sender"] in dict1.keys()):
             dict1[eachitem["sender"]]["amount"]=dict1[eachitem["sender"]]["amount"]+eachitem["amount"]
             dict1[eachitem["sender"]]["reciever"]+=1

        else:
            dict1[eachitem["sender"]]={"reciever":1,"amount":eachitem["amount"]}

print(dict1)
```

output

```
{'a': {'reciever': 2, 'amount': 7}, 'c': {'reciever': 1, 'amount': 10}}
```