# How can I group sum and count in Python creating a new dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

So, I'm trying to do something similar to this:

```
select a, b, c, sum(d), sum(e), count(*)
from df 
group by 1,2,3
```

In other words, I have this:

```
a        b        c    d    e
Billy    Profesor 1    10   5
Billy    Profesor 1    17   3
Andrew   Student  8    2    7
```

And I want the output to be:

```
a        b        c    d    e    count
Billy    Profesor 1    27   8    2
Andrew   Student  8    2    7    1
```

I tried this, and it partially worked:

```
df.groupby(['a','b','c']).sum().reset_index()
```

I still couldn't make it work for the count. I also tried the answer in the post [Group dataframe and get sum AND count?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38174155/group-dataframe-and-get-sum-and-count), but using the agg function make things very messy and it counts every column.

UPDATE: I changed column c because I have a numeric column to group, but not sum.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a join:

```
groups=df.groupby(['a','b','c'])
groups.sum().join(groups.size().to_frame('count')).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
        a         b   c   d  e  count
0  Andrew   Student  CA   2  7      1
1   Billy  Profesor  NY  27  8      2
```

Comment: don't know what happened, but for me, a few 'Andrew's disappeared on the output

Comment: yeah, I tried to fillna with some arbitrary string, but it didn't fixed. I'm losing a few Andrews and Billies by using this code. Not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

Try [`NamedAgg`](https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/whatsnew/v0.25.0.html)

```
df_final = df.groupby(['a','b','c'], sort=False).agg(d=('d', 'sum'), 
                                                     e=('e', 'sum'), 
                                                     count=('e', 'count')).reset_index()

Out[12]:
        a         b   c   d  e  count
0   Billy  Profesor  NY  27  8      2
1  Andrew   Student  CA   2  7      1
```

Comment: is there any other way? The problem with this is that I actually don't have only d and e to sum, it's at least 100 columns to summarise

Comment: you may construct a dictionary for `NamedAgg` for columns you want to sum using dict comprehension